# Prompts not filling in report query SQL in BO Webi

Tags: business-objects, business-intelligence

I am using BO 6.5.
When I edit the reports for pulling report query.. the prompts values in the 'SQL' are not autofilled.
Sometimes I get the query fully with values substituted for the prompts.. but most of the times the prompts are not substituted with respective values in the SQL.
i.e., when i see the SQL of the report I'm seeing the below:

> ( ( CALENDAR_DAY.Measure_Type_Code ) = @Prompt('SYS_TimePeriod','A',{'Day','WTD'},MONO,CONSTRAINED)  )

instead of

> ( ( CALENDAR_DAY.Measure_Type_Code ) = 'DAY'  )

How can I make sure that every time I see the report SQL, i get the query with prompts filled in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the report and then go back to your dataprovider to see the SQL, then it will have replaced your prompts with the actual values :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you view the SQL from the SQL Viewer in the Query Panel, this is actually how Business Objects behaves.

When you see the @Prompt() inside the SQL, that value will be replaced by the value(s) actually entered in the prompts.  To see the exact values, you will need to see the SQL as the database executes the query.

Comment: I too thought the same. but some times Im able to see the prompts substituted with values in the SQL viewer. and so was thinking there might be a way (like any change in settings or so) to pull the qry with prompts filled.